# Caching queryset in django rest framwork?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework, memcached

I have a large queryset  and I have a Paginator for the generics.ListAPIView. I want to cache that queryset with its all page, but i think it doesn't work that way. I've been trying to figure out how to cache the queryset with the Paginator but I don't seem to find a way to make it work with Django Rest.

this is my pagination class:

```
class StandardPagesPagination(PageNumberPagination):
  page_size = 35

  def get_paginated_response(self, data):
      return Response({
          'links': {
              'next': self.get_next_link(),
              'previous': self.get_previous_link()
          },
          'count': self.page.paginator.count,
          'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
          'results': data
      })
```

and this is my view:

```
class OyunlarList(generics.ListAPIView):
    # queryset = Oyunlar.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,filters.SearchFilter,filters.OrderingFilter]
    search_fields=['title']
    filterset_fields=['categories__name','platform','categories__category_id','game_id']
    ordering_fields = ['title', 'release_date','click_count','popularite']
    pagination_class = StandardPagesPagination


    serializer_class = OyunlarSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset=Oyunlar.objects.all().order_by('click_count').prefetch_related('categories')
        #queryset=Oyunlar.objects.raw("select 'game_id' AS id,'title','base_price','en_ucuz' from oyunlar ")


        return queryset

    @method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 3))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(OyunlarList, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to give user a more smooth experience.